# What determines the encoding of then data you receive from an HTTP POST?

Tags: web-applications, post, character-encoding

There's one mechanism concerning characters encoding which I'm really not familiar with and I'd like to have detailed information as to what's going on and I'd like to know how I can control things in my webapp.

When a user pastes non-ASCII characters (like "ä æ é à") on my website, say in a form that shall then get POSTed, what does exactly happen and how is it determined?

For example, if I go to an HTML page using the charset iso-8859-1:

```
<HEAD>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1">
```

and I cut'n'paste *"ä æ é à"* to a window which is using Unicode chars, I see the correct *"ä æ é à"* characters.

It's not entirely clear to me what happened there: did the browser convert the characters to some encoding when reading the iso-latin-1 encoded page and then convert these characters again when I paste them into another window?

Can I programmatically "force" the encoding that shall be used when a form on a webpage shall be posted?

Will the browser be responsible for sending/encoding the characters correctly?

Can I force the encoding used in a form to be different than the one used in the webpage? (for example to allow POSTing in UTF-8 even though the page is in iso-latin-1... Note that I do not want to do that, it's just to understand what is it going on under the hood).

I guess my question may boil down to: *"What should I do to not run into encoding issues?"* but if someone could explain the above to me I'd have a much clearer picture as to what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser will use the same encoding as specified in the `charset` attribute of the HTTP `Content-Type` response header of the page which contains the form which is to be submitted. You can determine it for your own site with help of among others [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com):

[image]

The one in the `<meta>` tag will only be used when the whole HTTP `Content-Type` response header is **completely absent**, which may happen when the server didn't set it (which is very unlikely), or when you saved the webpage to local disk file system and then viewed from it by `file://` protocol.

So, if you have character encoding problems, apparently you (or your server) didn't set the `charset` attribute in the HTTP `Content-Type` response header. In that case the browser will decide it by itself what charset to use, which is often the platform default charset, but in some cases (e.g. Firefox) based on a "smart guess" based on the webpage's content. The one in the `<meta>` tag is a good fallback, but it won't be used when the page is served over HTTP.

In your question history I see that you're a Java developer, so you're possibly dealing with JSP/Servlet pages (or JSP/Servlet based frameworks), in that case you may find this article useful: [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: +1 thanks...  Yup indeed, it's for a Java webapp using JSPs.  So I'll read that article with great interest : )