# Encoding differs when POSTing from iPad to ASP

Tags: ios, encoding, asp-classic

I've made an iPad app that posts data to a ASP script. Data is then stored in UTF-8 in the MySQL db. Today one of the users posted data which made an error:

Data posted:

```
Jeanette Sjösvärd, Uttke Renata, Håkan Giljam
```

Data saved in log and db:

```
Jeanette SjÃ¶svÃ¤rd, Uttke Renata, HÃ¥kan Giljam
```

When reading data from the database, the text is full of "Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶" (should be "å ä ö")

The log also saves the original post data the way it arrives to the server in percentage format:

```
Jeanette%20Sj%C3%B6sv%C3%A4rd%2C%20Uttke%20Renata
```

When posting all the data again (copy and paste that percentage-encoded block) from an ASP page, the data gets saved without any encoding issues.

**Facts**

- Full posted data is about 18kB
- All ASP pages contains `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>` on top

**Questions/ideas**

- Why does the ASP script read the data in different ways, depending on the sender?
- Why did it just happen 1 out of 100 times?
- Is there any encoding information that is/should be sent along with a POST request?
- Could it be depending on some single special character in the data?
- Does the iPad use any other encoding than UTF-8 as a standard? (The iPad is set to Swedish)

Comment: The UTF-8 sequence for "ö" is `C3 B6`, so it seems that the clients sends correctly encoded data. "Ã" is the Unicode point U+00C3, and "¶" is U+00B6, that looks as if the server interprets the bytes separately, and not as a UTF-8 sequence. I have no knowledge about ASP at all, but perhaps this helps a bit to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Found this thread: [What determines the encoding of then data you receive from an HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040064/what-determines-the-encoding-of-then-data-you-receive-from-an-http-post)

Will look into the encoding header of the post request. But how could I detect if posted data isn't UTF-8 and in that case convert it?

Follow-up in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656710/how-to-detect-post-encoding-and-convert-to-utf-8-in-asp